# Why does Maxscale not pass the slave in master with the failover?

Tags: failover, master-slave, maxscale

I just set up a MariaDB Eslace and master server. I would like to use the failover function, but when I stop the mariadb master service, MaxScale recognizes its stop and tells me that it will switch the slave to master ... But the slave remains in the slave state.

maxscale.cnf :

cat maxscale.cnf

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
log_augmentation = 1
ms_timestamp = 1
log_info= 1
log_debug= 1
log_augmentation=1

[db1_master]
type=server
address=10.126.26.205
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[db2_slave]
type=server
address=10.126.26.242
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=db1_master,db2_slave
user=maxscaleuser
passwd=XXXXXXX
monitor_interval=1000
auto_rejoin=true
auto_failover=1
failover_timeout=5
failcount=2


[Read-Only-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1_master, db2_slave
user=maxscaleuser
passwd=XXXXXXX
router_options=master

[Read-Write-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
servers=db1_master, db2_slave
user=maxscaleuser
passwd=XXXXXX
router_options=master

[MaxAdmin-Service]
type=service
router=cli

[Read-Only-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Only-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4008

[Read-Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Read-Write-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=4006

[MaxAdmin-Listener]
type=listener
service=MaxAdmin-Service
protocol=maxscaled
socket=default
```

---

maxadmin list services

```
--------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------
Service Name              | Router Module     | #Users | Total Sessions | Backend databases
--------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------
Read-Only-Service         | readconnroute     |      1 |              1 | db1_master, db2_slave
Read-Write-Service        | readconnroute     |      1 |              4 | db1_master, db2_slave
MaxAdmin-Service          | cli               |      2 |              4 |
--------------------------+-------------------+--------+----------------+-------------------
```

---

Master MariaDB :

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW MASTER STATUS;

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000012 |      342 | masterdb     |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```